# Determine whether any text follows an anchor tag (Or: ':last-child' selector that counts text nodes)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

When a user posts a link in my forum, I'm going to replace it with a preview of that linked content (something like the Facebook news feed). However, I only want to replace the link if it appears at the end of a paragraph (or if it's the only element in a paragraph).

For example:

I **do** want to replace the link in this case:

```
<p>Check out this cool website: 
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></p>
```

but I **don't** want to replace it in this case:

```
<p>Check out this cool website:
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a> – isn't it great?</p>
```

To accomplish this, I need to differentiate between links that have text after them and links that don't. My first thought was to test `$the_link_in_question.is(":last-child")`, but then I realized that `:last-child` ignores text nodes.

I suppose I could do something like:

```
$the_link_in_question.parent().contents().last()[0] == $the_link_in_question[0]
```

But this approach makes me throw up in my mouth. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check the `.html()` to see if it ends in `</a>`:

```
if (/<\/a>$/i.test($p.html())) {
    var previewMe = $p.children().last();
}
```

You'll need a more complicated regex if it's possible that your anchors can get wrapped in other elements, e.g. `<strong>` (your original approach couldn't handle these cases either):

```
<p>content <strong><a href="...">link</a></strong></p>
```

In which case, you can use this regex:

```
/<\/a>(<\/.+?>)*$/
```

Comment: +1 I like it :) added this demo http://jsfiddle.net/YpWGE/ and also added `/s` in case of trailing spaces (feel free to correct if I've done it wrong!)

Comment: @lnrbob - great demo, thanks for that! `\s` is a good addition too.

Comment: Sigh – I guess I could drop down to text processing, but it always makes me feel dirty! (Though the fact that your approach handles the `<strong>` case is definitely a plus). Ideally I'd keep this at the DOM level of abstraction though – it just seems like regexes will be more fragile. Is there any way to do it with only DOM / jQuery operations?

Comment: @Horace, I agree that regex seems fragile. jQuery has always been weak when dealing with text nodes - `.contents()` is the only function it provides. Yes, you can do it with only DOM operations, but it would have to be recursive I imagine (start at p, get last node, check if nodeType is element, if so recurse. End at non-element nodes, or when tag is 'a').